# Ring homomorphism f from the field F into the endomorphism ring of the group of vectors - what for?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules

I am familiar with the definition of vector space.

In the Wiki definition of vector space, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Alternative_formulations_and_elementary_consequences. Wiki said:

1. the first four axioms are equivalent to requiring the set of vectors to be an abelian group under addition.

I agree.

2. The remaining axioms give this group an F-module structure.

I agree.

3. In other words, there is a ring homomorphism f from the field F into the endomorphism ring of the group of vectors. Then scalar multiplication av is defined as (f(a))(v).

**Question**: I dont understand the importance of **ring homomorphism f** and the **endomorphism ring of the group of vectors**. I understand scalar multiplication av. But I also dont understand why we need (f(a))(v). Could some one rephrase it more simply? Why are these discussions necessary?

Answer (score 2):

The claim is that if we are given an Abelian group $V$ together with a ring homomorphism $f:F\to {\rm End}(V)$, then it determines a vector space structure on $V$.

Namely define the addition as the group operation of $V$ and scalar multiplication by
$$a\cdot v:=f(a)(v)\,.$$
Then axiom $a\cdot(v+w)=a\cdot v+a\cdot w$ holds because $f(a)\in{\rm End}(V)$ and axioms $(ab)\cdot v=a\cdot(b\cdot v)$ and $(a+b)\cdot v=a\cdot v+b\cdot v$ follow by $f$ being a ring homomorphism.

Conversely, for a given vector space $V$, this homomorphism is just
$$f(a)=v\mapsto av\,.$$

Comment: thanks +1 so much